# Is it possible to make a large Spinner Item, break into multiple lines in XML in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner, arrays

I have a Spinner to which I add entries statically. I know I can use an adapter and have a text view for items an so on... But that is not what I'm looking for. What I want is to tell the spinner to break down large items in multiple lines in XML. I just need to know is there any way to do that in layout file or 
my  ?

here is my spinner which is filled from a string-array:

> ```
> <Spinner android:id="@+id/spr_my_spinner" 
>   android:entries="@array/my_string_array" 
>   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>   android:layout_weight="3" 
>   android:layout_width="0dp"
>
>   />
> ```

Comment: I guess you will have to implement your own adapter for that...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Supposedly I have no choice.